# How do you highlight ops' messages in Irssi?

Tags: irc, irssi

I'm watching a large IRC channel with a lot of noise and precious few ops. How can I have all messages from ops highlighted?

Answer (score 5):

If there is only few people who you want to highlight, you can just add multiple hilights. For help with hilight, see

```
/help hilight
```

If that's not practical, [trigger.pl](http://scripts.irssi.org/html/trigger.pl.html) can help you.